# Breaking a loop inside another loop

Tags: loops, break, python-3.5

I am trying to break 2 loops in Python, with one loop inside the other. Of course, when you use the break function in a loop it will only break the loop it's in. Here's the code:

```
while True:   #Want to break this
    x, y, z = sense.get_accelerometer_raw().values()
    x = abs(x)
    y = abs(y)
    z = abs(z)
    sense.show_message(strftime('%H:%M', gmtime()), scroll_speed= 0.05, text_colour=[0, 255, 0], back_colour=[255, 0, 0])
    if x > 2 or y > 2 or z > 2 :   #Want to break this as well
        break #Break goes here??
```

I want to break the loop started on the top line and the loop started in line 7. How?

Comment: newsflash: `if` is _not_ a loop. And remove the irrelevant rasppi & 3.5 tags.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: not even that: it's a duplicate of "how to break from if in Python", but the question doesn't exist!

Comment: I'm an idiot- I just realised what I have done. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` is ***not*** a loop. `If` is a statement that takes a boolean (true or false) and executes the code depending on the result.

That being said, what you have written will work.

```
if x > 2 or y > 2 or z > 2 :   #Want to break this as well
    break #Break goes here??
```

This code will break the `while True` loop if `x > 2 or y > 2 or z > 2`.